# Is there an c++ function from Armadillo for selecting a column from a matrix?”

Tags: c++, armadillo

I'm looking for selecting a column from a matrix H for example, knowingly that a have the index off this column

I searched in Armadillio

Comment: Can you provide a mathematical example of what you want to do?

Comment: h = [[ 0.65670886,  0.43024765],
       [ 0.6688264 ,  0.46121732],
       [ 0.96284109,  0.73983768],
       [ 0.94589245,  0.41653401],
       [ 0.90351229,  0.65803306]]

Comment: for example  I want to extract the first column using a Armadillo's functions so:

Comment: So Vec_H = [0.65670886, 0.6688264,0.962841090.0.94589245, 0.90351229] T

Answer (score 1):

According to http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat you can use `X.col(col_number)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the .col(col_number) function, or the .cols(first_col, last_col) function.

See [here](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat).